# visual studio code terminal boilerplate

Tags: python

Whenever I run a python program in VSC, in addition to the output I get a big load of identical boilerplate on every run, then the actual output - i.e.

cd /home/jim/Downloads/lxmed ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/jim/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 38443 /home/jim/Downloads/lxmed/myprog.py

OUTPUT

Is there any way to suppress the boilerplate?

Comment: That's the full command resulting from your launch configuration to run the program.

Comment: Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-support-options-and-settings-in-visual-studio